# Possible to add large amount of DOM nodes without browser choking?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I have a webpage on my site that displays a table, reloads the XML source data every 10 seconds (with an XmlHttpRequest), and then updates the table to show the user any additions or removals of the data. To do this, the JavaScript function first clears out all elements from the table and then adds a new row for each unit of data.

Recently, I battled thru a number of memory leaks in Internet Explorer caused by this DOM destroy-and-create code (most of them having to do with circular references between JavaScript objects and DOM objects, and the JavaScript library we are using quietly keeping a reference to every JS object created with `new Element(...)` until the page is unloaded).

With the memory problems solved, we've now uncovered a CPU-based problem: when the user has a large amount of data to view (100+ units of data, which equals 100 `<tr>` nodes to create, plus all of the table cells for each column), the process ties up the CPU until Internet Explorer prompts the user with:

> Stop running this script?
>   A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly.
>   If it continues to run, your computer may become
>   unresponsive.

It seems that running the row-and-cell-creation code times 100+ pieces of data is what is causing the CPU usage to spike, the function to take "too long" (from IE's perspective) to run, thus causing IE to generate this warning for the user. I've also noticed that while the "update screen" function runs for the 100 rows, IE does not re-render the table contents until the function completes (since the JS interpreter is using 100% CPU for that time period, I assume).

So my question is: Is there any way in JavaScript to tell the browser to pause JS execution and re-render the DOM? If not, are there any strategies for handling creating large amounts of DOM nodes and *not* having the browser choke?

One method I can think of would be to handle the "update table" logic asynchronously; that is, once the Ajax method to reload the XML data is complete, put the data into some sort of array, and then set a function (using `setInterval()`) to run which will handle one element of the array at a time. However this seems a little bit like re-creating threading in a JavaScript environment, which seems like it could get very complicated (i.e. what if another Ajax data request fires while I'm still re-creating the table's DOM nodes?, etc.)

---

**update**: Just wanted to explain why I'm accepting RoBurg's answer. In doing some testing, I've found that the `new Element()` method in my framework (I'm using [mootools](http://mootools.net/)) is about 2x as slow as the traditional `document.createElement()` in IE7. I ran a test to create 1000 `<spans>` and add them to a `<div>`, using `new Element()` takes about 1800ms on IE7 (running on Virtual PC), the traditional method takes about 800ms.

My test also revealed an even quicker method, at least for a simple test such as mine: using [DocumentFragments as described by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/). Running the same test on the same machine with IE7 took 247ms, a **9x** improvement from my original method!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100 `<tr>`'s isn't really that much... are you still using that framework's `new Element()`?  That might be the cause of it.

You should test the speed of `new Element()` vs `document.createElement()` vs `.innerHTML`

Also try building the dom tree "in memory" then append it to the document at the end.

Finally watch that you're not looking at .length too often, or other bits and bobs like that.

Comment: I've read that building up a sub-tree and then adding it to document at the end can leak objects as well - have you had that experience?

Comment: Hmm nope.  I've had other leaks but never heard of that one.

Comment: my sources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/leakpatterns.aspx look under "cross-page leaks" - note though that these are from 2005

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problems at round 3000 table rows of complex data, so there is something not entirely right with your code.  How is it running in firefox ? Can you check in several different browsers.

Are you binding to onPropertyChange anywhere ? This is a really dangerous ie event that has caused me severe ie-specific headaches earlier. Are you using CSS selectors anywhere ? These are notoriously slow on ie.

Comment: Negative to your last two questions. Firefox is ok, but noticeably unresponsive during the update. I'll investigate improving the code itself

Answer (score 1):

You could create a string representation and add it as `innerHTML` of a node.

Answer (score 0):

You could cloneNode(false) the element to be repeated, and then use that for the loop, instead of generating the element each time.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using one large `for` loop to render all the data in one big step. Look at breaking up the data into smaller chunks instead.

Render each smaller chunk with a `while` loop. After that chunk is done, call the next chunk with `setTimeout` [time 1ms] to give the browser a "breather".

You can avoid using the `while` loop altogether and just use a `setTimeout`.

Using the `setTimeout` technique **will** slow down the execution speed a bit, but you should not get the warning message.

Another thing to look at is to not append each element individually to the document. Look into creating a new `tbody`, appending the new rows to the new `tbody`, and append the `tbody` to the table.

There are a lot of other things that can cause a slow application. It can be fun to flush them all out.

There is a neat study of the warning here: http://ajaxian.com/archives/what-causes-the-long-running-script-warning.