# adding large amount of elements to DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

in my web application, I have to retrive huge amount of data and to create a table with the data ( table with around  800 rows, 10 columns)
When, I am directly adding elements through `append()` method, the browser doesnot respond for a while.
for accessing the huge data, I am using web workers for ajax call.
As, we cannot manipulate DOM from web workers, what should I do??
thanks :)

***edit***:
If I want some functions like hide() (jQuery hide) over it, will innerHtml work??

Comment: If what format is the data? JSON? In that case, I recommend a JavaScript templating engine (e.g. Handlebars) to create the entire HTML string, and then append that string to the DOM at once.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429174/possible-to-add-large-amount-of-dom-nodes-without-browser-choking)

Comment: You could try preparing the nodes with a DocumentFragment and then appending that once. I don't think the browser would need to block during the fragment creation.

Comment: Also, you don't need workers for Ajax calls. The processing requirements of making and receiving Ajax are minimal.

Comment: What do you want `hide()` to do that you feel might solve your problem?

Comment: we need to achieve functionality, so for that we need hide() method

Comment: I honestly can't interpret that comment as an explanation: what is that you're trying to do? Why do you feel that `hide()` will achieve what you want? If you feel it does what you want, have you tried using it? What went wrong? I'm not trying to challenge you, I'm trying to work out how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some JavaScript templates engine to avoid manual appending the elements step by step or building the innerHTML string.

For example http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating.

Say you have a template somewhere in your **HTML**:

```
<script type="text/html" id="user_rows_tpl">
    <% for(var y = 0, l = users.length; l > y; y++) { %>
        <tr id="user-row-<%=y%>">
            <td><%=users[y].name%></td>
            <td><%=users[y].surname%></td>
            <td><%=users[y].age%></td>       
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</script>​
```

And then you're using this template in your **JavaScript** to render your objects:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById("userTable");
    table.innerHTML = tmpl("user_rows_tpl", {
        users: getUsers()
    });
</script>
```

For test I've created 1000 user objects and rendered them in table.
The average rendering time is about 20-25ms in Google Chrome. Not bad, isn't it?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/XA8dG/)**

Answer (score 1):

**Note** : *Accessing DOM elements with JavaScript is slow so in order to have a more responsive page.*

you can do this by

```
var buffer = [];
setInterval(function(){ $("#div").html(buffer.join(""); buffer = []; }, 1000);

buffer.push("html");
buffer.push("html");
```

and check this [link for the performance](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03)

also check this link [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#min_dom)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a table plugin that supports lazy insertion of DOM elements (i.e. on demand). [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) offers a wealth of features, [including this one](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/defer_render.html). It will also help you cut down on the size of the code you have to write.

Comment: can u explain me how to do lazy insertion of Dom elements??
thanx :)